# Android Compose app crashes with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

The full stacktrace is:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Landroidx/compose/runtime/internal/LiveLiteralInfo;.key()Ljava/lang/String;"
                                                                                                        at dalvik.system.VMDebug.nativeAttachAgent(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at dalvik.system.VMDebug.attachAgent(VMDebug.java:572)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.attemptAttachAgent(ActivityThread.java:3934)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleAttachAgent(ActivityThread.java:3944)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2054)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I can't stable reproduce this bug and understand when and why it happens